# Sending secure data over the network in iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, security, authentication, encryption

I have a query regarding sending secure data over the network in iPhone.

What should be used to secure credit-card, bank acct# etc. information which is sent over wireless network.

Is there any difference in methods if we use a native-app or a web-app?

Are there any direct APIs available for this?

Any tutorial will be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

So where exactly the certificate/encryption is needed?
Is following procedure correct?

1]Make connection to “https:” web-service using NSURLConnection

2]The server should implement SSL/TLS Server will respond with a digital certificate (*.p12    file)

3]Client side authorization will be done. (Whether the obtained certificate is trusted or
   not is checked. If trusted,then we can continue. Otherwise exit gracefully)

4]Now Secure Channel is established. Send the data (Credit card info. etc) to server. Encryption can be done using public/private key pair

---

I am able to connect to a "http://" SOAP webservice. procedure:

1) Create a SOAP Envelope (With required i/p parameters)
 2) Make NSURL Object with required web service addr
3) Initialize 'NSMutableURLRequest' with above url
 4) Set parameters for NSMutableURLRequest
5) Initiate 'NSURLConnection' with above request.

After this automatically NSURLConnection methods are called. 
Now I want to connect to 'Https://' web-service and send sensitive info to it.

So,what extra needs to be done? Do I need to add extra methods or above approach works? (I send parameters as plain text from in http)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the receiving server-side code implements [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), the iphone's [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) and the alternative open-source [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) both support secure connections to *https* websites by default.

Comment: but how to send the password, credit card info securely?
We cant send it as plain text.
How to use encryption/Decryption?

what about Certificate, Key, and Trust Services?
How to use them?

Comment: What luvieere is suggesting would encrypt your sensitive data by virtue of HTTPS. This is the same way eCommerce websites secure their online transactions.